# Putting dragon bone(s) into starling sprite sheet?

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite, starling-framework

My iOS game contains many tiles, and each of the tiles are animated. I have about 30 animated tiles. Now my question is: can i create dragon bones for each animation and store them in a starling sprite sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, I haven't done it but from what I understand (from this conversation)[http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/getting-all-assets-together-in-one-atlas#post-19274], one can edit a DragonBones atlas and add his own assets as well. Then use it as he would normally use his own Atlas.